# Using Google Forms is it possible to collect a list of respondents that is separate from their anonymous answers?

Tags: google-forms

new to this particular Stackexchange with a Google Forms question?

I need to a submit a survey to members in our organisation. I have built this survey in Google Forms. I need to record a list of respondents that remains unlinked to each member's anonymous responses, and members should only respond once. How can this be done?

In Google Forms, I can require an email to track respondents, but in *Responses > Summary* there is a list of names at the top and then the breakdown for each question. However in *Responses > Individual* I can see how each respondent answered.

Another attempted answer to this question in this forum suggested removing the required email, and adding a Name field, but it still shows a list of each respondents answers under the *Responses > Individual* tab. So the name is still connected to their survey responses.

I would also like to allow each email to only respond once to the survey, without requiring a Google Sign In.

Is it possible to build the survey as I've done, keep it anonymous with no email requirement or name field, but perhaps send each email in our organisation a unique URL that somehow tracks who responded, separately from their answers in Google Forms?

Any ideas or approaches to solving this? I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [web apps.se]. This can't be done by using only Google Forms. Asking for "any ideas... " makes the question primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rubén. I am seeking a technical solution to the problem rather than opinions per se, although I suppose one approach might be considered better than another as a matter of opinion. As I said, I am wondering if there is a workaround, where two apps might be linked to work to acheive this, by generating unique URLs is it possible to track who replies by recording who follows the link, and keep the answers summary from Google Forms separate and not linked to that list of emails? Is there a webapp that can be used to generate unique URLs for each email in a list?

Comment: To ask for web app recommendations please go to [softwarerecs.se].